# Несколько Jquery на странице

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, как побороть следующую проблему:
Пытаюсь подключить слайдер на страницу. На сайте уже есть бибилиотека jquery, но с ней слайдер работать отказывается. Подключаю еще одну прямо перед скриптами слайдера:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

В результате вся анимация сайта (она завязана на jquery) пропадает, но слайдер работает. Как мне подружить их?

Comment: Сегодня попробую, и отмечу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше всего переписать анимацию, чтобы работала с новым jQuery (на самом деле там немного, скорее всего).

А плохой вариант:

1. Грузим новый jQuery.
2. Грузим плагин слайдера.
3. Пишем [`<script>var newJq=jQuery.noConflict()</script>`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).
4. Грузим старый jQuery.
5. Когда надо вызвать плагин слайдера, пишем вместо `$(element).plugin()` **`newJq(element).plugin()`**.

Answer (score 1):

- Попробуйте подключить самую последнюю версию jQuery
- После неё `jQuery migrate`: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js